# CodeIgniter CSS .htaccess 404 error

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess

I am building an admin section in codeigniter for my site and wanted to have a separate CSS folder for the CSS files for the admin section as they are going differ to those for the main site.

Current my CSS files sit in `assets/css`

I added and extra folder to that called admin and placed my new CSS files in that ie

```
assets/css/admin/css/style.css
```

However when I click the link in source code view to that stylesheet, I get a 404.

My current .htaccess reads as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|editor|css\/|admin|js|scripts|images|img|media|xml|user_guide|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

What would I need to do to enable this file.

Note the strange thing is I have 4 CSS files in the folder, two of them whem clicked in the view source ope okay, and 2 of them contain the 404.

Comment: How are you creating the links to the CSS in your view(s)? Are they relative or absolute?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `\/` in front of `css`?

Comment: Hi there, the links that I am using are as follows: <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/admin/style.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">,Yes there was no \/ in the first instance and I added that as a way of getting it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```